# appView is Null in Cordova Android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

As in Android Cordova 5.1.1 CordovaWebView is not working, I had tried with

```
WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
```

instead of

```
CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(this);
```

But **appView** is always null in my case:

below is code snippet

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
 }
 public void init() {
    WebView wV = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
}
```

But I get **appView= null** and program fails every time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have overwritten the default init method from `CordovaActivity` which sets the value of `appView`.

Name the `init` method differently (or call `super.init()` inside of it if this was your intention) and make sure you call it after `loadUrl` is called.